# MVC controller encoding JSON with Json(object) vs JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(object)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

In my current MVC application I perform an AJAX call to the controller. The controller gets an object from the database and returns it in the form of a JSON response. My confusion is between using the [Controller.Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.118).aspx) method vs [JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize))(object). My object I am converting is a simple class called `PhoneSerializable` with a few public properties of type `string` and `int`.

I have the following:

```
var serializedPhone = jsSerializer.Serialize(new PhoneSerializable(phone));
return new ContentResult {Content = serializedPhone, ContentType = "application/json"};
```

This works correctly and I get a JSON response that my AJAX caller can parse.
Yet some online examples I have seen use this instead:

```
return Json(new PhoneSerializable(phone));
```

The response of this has mostly `null` properties and a `DenyGet` header which means it failed parsing or something. The documentation for the `Json(object)` method states that it uses the same javascript serializer for the object yet it fails to convert my simple object to JSON.

What am I missing? I would like to use `Json(object)` since it is much cleaner but I cannot seem to get it to work.

EDIT WITH ANSWER:

The `Json()` method was defaulting to "DenyGet" adding more parameters fixed the issue and it now works:

```
return Json(new PhoneSerializable(phone), 
            "application/json", 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Json` method from the `Controller` base class simply returns a new object of type `JsonResult`, using the following overload:

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data)
{
    return this.Json(data, null, null, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}

protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(
                       object data, 
                       string contentType, 
                       Encoding contentEncoding,
                       JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = data,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
    };
}
```

After you `return Json(new PhoneSerialize(phone));`, the controller eventually invokes a method called `ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)`, which internally does the same serialization with `JsonSerializer`:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    if (this.JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
                            string.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod,
                                          "GET",
                                          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed);
    }
    HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType))
    {
        response.ContentType = this.ContentType;
    }
    else
    {
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
    }
    if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
    {
        response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
    }
    if (this.Data != null)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        if (this.MaxJsonLength.HasValue)
        {
            javaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = this.MaxJsonLength.Value;
        }
        if (this.RecursionLimit.HasValue)
        {
            javaScriptSerializer.RecursionLimit = this.RecursionLimit.Value;
        }
        response.Write(javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(this.Data));
    }
}
```

This basically means you're passing both `DenyGet` as a default parameter, yet your method is a "GET", which ends up throwing an `InvalidOperationException`. You should specify the "AllowGet" explicitly to avoid this:

```
return Json(new PhoneSerializable(phone), 
            "application/json", 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I see. So the Json method was simply defaulting to "DenyGet". It works now after using this return statement instead: return Json(new PhoneSerializable(phone), "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  Thank you.